# Can i use HTML::Template in my perl scripts?

Tags: html, perl, templates

I am using godaddy.com for my website hosting

Can i use HTML::Template in my perl scripts? I want to send perl script output to Template file, which internally generate the web page and display on the browser. But while i am using use HTML::Template in my perl script, i am getting error.

Thanks,
Devesh

Comment: What error? What's your code? - You need to be a lot more specific. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10862327/edit) to add the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check if `HTML::Template` is installed on godaddy servers by running the command from this support article:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1488/can-i-add-perl-modules-to-my-hosting-account

If the `perl -MFile::Find=find ...` call returns HTML::Template in the list, you might use it incorrectly.

If the command does not return the module in the list, you may try to create a local installation of the module (for example, in a `lib` directory within your web root directory) and include HTML::Template from the local directory. Something like:

```
BEGIN { push(@INC, '/path/to/the/lib/directory/') };
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Template;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to create a local installation of the module?